# AWS Serverless how to serve static files from S3 and some other through lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, serverless-framework

I am creating website on AWS using serverless framework.
There are 3 parts which I need to serve clients:

1. endpoints of lambda functions (/getusers)
2. index.html served throught lambda (I need to insert some constants to it)
3. static html, js, css, img files, which should be served directly from S3, without going throught costly lambda.

How do I accomplish that? I need all parts of the app to be able to cooperate thus, probably on the same domain. I need index.html and js files to be able to call the lambda endpoints (setted up by API Gateway). Also I would like all files be cached throught CloudFront. I searched google but did not found any example.

Answer (score 2):

The [serverless-apigateway-service-proxy](https://github.com/serverless-operations/serverless-apigateway-service-proxy#s3) plugin will create API Gateway endpoints backed by services other than Lambda, including S3. Here is a complete example `serverless.yml` that defines an S3 bucket of public static resources and creates an API method connected to it at path `/static/{asset}`:

```
service: s3-static-asset-example

frameworkVersion: '2'

plugins:
  - serverless-apigateway-service-proxy

provider:
  name: aws

custom:
  apiGatewayServiceProxies:
    - s3:
        path: /static/{asset}
        method: get
        action: GetObject
        bucket:
          Ref: StaticAssetBucket
        key:
          pathParam: asset
        cors: true

resources:
  Resources:
    StaticAssetBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        VersioningConfiguration:
          Status: Enabled
        PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
          BlockPublicAcls: true
          BlockPublicPolicy: true
          IgnorePublicAcls: true
          RestrictPublicBuckets: true
        BucketEncryption:
          ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
            - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
                SSEAlgorithm: AES256

  Outputs:
    StaticAssetBucket:
      Value:
        Ref: StaticAssetBucket
```

A file `app.js` placed in the bucket

```
aws s3 cp app.js s3://s3-static-asset-example-dev-staticassetbucket-xxxxxx
```

is made available at

```
https://xxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/static/app.js
```

Since each service proxy integration has its own path, a Serverless app can include a mix of proxy integrations and normal Lambda method handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You can host you static files on the S3 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html with the custom domain https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html, you can also use the CloudFront https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-cloudfront-walkthrough.html.

API Gateway can be configured with custom domain via CloudFront - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html

Comment: Ok, I know these, but how do I connect BOTH api gateway AND S3/cloudfront to the same domain? How will the domain know which request to redirect to which?

Comment: CloudFront aliased with custom domain should be set up with multiple origins - S3 and API Gateway. Decision which origin to use can be managed by the behaviors. See https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-distribution-serve-content/ for more details. You can for example decide to pick up API origin if request URL contains <yourdomain>/api path, and S3 origin for all other requests.

Comment: how do I do that? Provide an example in yaml file.